# Is there any compiler IR paradigms other than Three Address Code and Static Single Assignment (SSA) Form?

Tags: compilers

Specifically, I have tried boiling down the operations of a VM into the smallest possible standardized units and arrived at this:

```
allocate_stack(size)
fetch(offset_from_stack_pointer)
store(offset_from_stack_pointer)
call(index)
```

So you might have:

```
allocate_stack 6
fetch -2
store 0
fetch -1
store 1
call 72
```

Basically, the `allocate_stack` would tell you how much space you are allocating for fields in the stack. Then the `fetch` would queue up something relative to the stack to be stored (or `fetch_a` would fetch an absolute address). Then `store` would store the fetched value in the space relative to the stack (or `store_a` for absolute position). And finally, `call <index>` would call that specific function.

So basically these are 2-address codes instead of 3-address codes. Does anything like this exist out there where they've expanded upon the idea to find compiler optimizations and such, like 3-address-code and SSA form? If not like this, does anything else exist outside of 3-address-code and SSA form?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely common approach to designing abstract machines for non-imperative languages. See, for example, [the G machine](https://digitalcollections.ohsu.edu/concern/etds/v692t655f?locale=en) or [the WAM](http://wambook.sourceforge.net/) (which uses the same technique for heap allocation).